# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) doesn't show arrow if called from non Activity class

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my Activity I want to show arrow to left of ActionBar icon, so in Activity I write:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

It works fine, but I decide move `ActionBar` initialization to another class and use it for all activities in my application, new class for this:

```
    public class Utils {
    public static void initActionBar(Activity activity, boolean homeIconNeeded) {
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(homeIconNeeded);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_background));
    }

    public static void initActionBar(ActionBar actionBar, boolean homeIconNeeded) {
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(SmartVmsApplication.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_background));
    }
}
```

Then in my activity I insert in `onCreate()` callback `initActionBar(this, true)`, however **arrow doesn’t appear**, no matters I passed `Activity` or `ActionBar` as parameter and it is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` method.